# Keras: color_mode = 'grayscale' does not convert to grayscale

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to read a dataset from directory `data` and I want the photos to be grayscaled.

```
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('data', shuffle=True, color_mode='grayscale')
```

When I print the results, the images are not grayscaled:
[image]

How can I grayscale an image with keras?

Comment: Yes they are, you're just displaying them with a colored palette.

Comment: You should read about [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the " cmap " parameter to your imshow method :

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```